# Paypal integration error

Tags: python, django, paypal, payment-gateway, django-paypal

I am using django rest framework to integrate paypal. But I am always getting

> Return to merchant error.

screenshot of the error:

[image]

I am Indian buyer and I want to accept international payment in USD. I have used django-paypal with following code:

```
def paypal_process(request):
try:
    host = request.get_host()
    paypal_dict = {
   'business': PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL ,
   'amount': '1',
   'item_name': 'Item_Name_xyz',
   'invoice': 'Test Payment Invoice',
   'currency_code': 'USD',
   'notify_url': 'http://localhost:8000/api/payment/payment_notify/',
   'return_url': 'http://localhost:8000/api/payment/payment_done/',
   'cancel_return': 'http://localhost:8000/api/payment/payment_canceled/',
    }
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    return render(request, 'paypal_process.html', {'form': form })
except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse("Exception " + str(e), status = status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, safe=False)
```

In settings.py I have following settings

```
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = 'xyz@abc.com'
PAYPAL_TEST = False
```

The code works fine when PAYPAL_TEST = True. But it gives the above error when in production.

By doing inspect element, I came across following error "UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY". I am trying to accept international payment in USD and I am Indian merchant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to answer my own question. As my business-email (receiver email) and the customer-email (sender email) were both from India and according to India banking regulations, one would not be able to send payments from one Indian account to another. So, to solve the issue from Indian customers I am accepting payment through paytm and for international customers through paypal. If you don't have access to international paypal account and want to test your website, then you can create a test account and test in sandbox mode. If it works, then most likely it will work on production also.